# Bounding rectangle for an item of CTreeCtrl

Tags: c++, tree, mfc

In the past we used a Stingray tree control to depict the legend of a map.

[image]

Now we want to apply a MFC `CTreeCtrl` to do this job. The Stingray control has the advantage that you can easily change the bounding rectangle for a special item. In order to draw images and text we used the `OnPaint` method.

The MFC API lists the method `GetItemRect`. Despite research in the internet we did not find an equivalent to set the rectangle for a particular item.

It would be nice if somebody could show us how to change the bounding rectangle of an item in order to create the legend of map.

Thanks in advance!

Note: Probably it would be enough to change the height and width of an item rectangle.

Comment: Customization points for Common Controls are frequently modeled as callbacks. When a tree-view control needs to render an item, it sends a [`TVM_GETITEMRECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvm-getitemrect) message, allowing clients to override default calculations. The item rectangle isn't stored as part of the control implementation, so there is no API to *"Set"* it either. You'll have to calculate it every time it is requested.

Answer (score 1):

The items' width is determined by their content (images + text). The height can be set by calling the `CTreeCtrl::`[`SetItemHeight`()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctreectrl-class?view=msvc-170#setitemheight) method (or sending the [`TVM_SETITEMHEIGHT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvm-setitemheight) message), although I wouldn't generally recommend this, because I think the system will allocate enough vertical space to hold the text and the images (the max of the two, but you can experiment). And it would best to avoid custom draw at all, and instead use the standard mechanism provided by Win32: image-list for your images, and standard text drawing. Why really use `OnPaint()`? Doesn't all the above cover your needs?

The `SetItemHeight()` documentation mentions:

> *`cyHeight`*
>
> *Specifies the new height of every item in the tree view, in pixels. If this argument is less than the height of the images, then it will
> be set to the height of the images.*

This means that you can control the items' height through the images' size (all members of the image-list are of the same size).

---

**EDIT:**

Yes, you want variable-height items, but you must check what's technically possible. Tree-View controls can only have items of the same height - the `TVM_SETITEMHEIGHT` message sets the height for all items. There is no some callback (or "notification" or what) asking the application about an item's height or rect. If you want items of variable height you have to draw the whole thing yourself, and in this case it doesn't even need to be a tree-view, it can just be a static control. And since you only want to use your control as a legend, ie no user-input, selections etc, it should be enough - it only needs to be expandable/retractable and maybe scrollable.

As for the image-list, all its members must be of the same size, and this is by Windows/API design. If yours are not, you can pad the smaller ones to the max size. It's just graphics work, easier done with the help of an image-editing application, like PaintShop Pro (proprietary, but very cheap) or GIMP (free, but with a weird UI), because the VS Image-Editor is a joke. You should better create a single image-file for the whole image-list, in order to mass-edit the images (legend labels). Don't know if images with Alpha (32-bit) will work with Image-Lists in Tree-View controls. If not, you will have to use a 24-bit image, with a background of the same color as the tree-view control.

Comment: Your answer sounds good, but there is still the problem that the legend can use images of different sizes. This implies that the tree control must reserve at least various heights for an item.

Comment: @Graphman, edited the post, pls check